# Where is the action log file physically saved in microsoft test manager?

Tags: automation, mtm

I want to know where actually these log files got saved in test manager?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, it's saved under SQL server. But I dont know how to get it from it (may be using SharePoint reporting service). If you look  the logs, you ll find the link like `mtm://<tfsSeverName>:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/p:trunk/Testing/testrun/open?id=118`.
I'm trying to find more info. If i get it, I ll post here.
In the mean time, I have created my customized logs with the test case, so that I can use it to debug somewhat.